# Select all records passing date as January 20 - PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to be able to query records from my table by passing in `January 20`, `January 21` as an example

I have found that the `EXTRACT` method can be used for cases such as this, but how could i use it when supplying a month and year. Would I need to format the string I'm providing into a date?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM kick_off) = 'January 20';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two extract calls and as `extract()` returns a number, you can't compare it with `January`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM kick_off) = 1
  and EXTRACT(year FROM kick_off) = 2020;
```

If you have an index on `kick_off` the above query wouldn't use that index. It's usually more efficient to use a range query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE kick_off >= date '2020-01-01'
  and kick_off  < date '2020-02-01'
```

Comment: Bit delayed getting back to you after you answered @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you, the two extract calls worked for my particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do that by using to_char on the kick_off column, but it's *really* bad design:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE to_char(kick_off, 'FMMonth YY') = 'January 20'
```

However, as @a_horse_with_no_name_correctly pointed out, it's most likely a bad idea because such a query will not use an index on the kick_off column, so a date range filter is preferable as it will perform much better in the presence of an index.

Also, the behaviour of the 'FMMonth' format is locale-dependent (relevant documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).